# MySQL yyyy-mm-ddThh:mm:ss.sssZ to yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I want to upload my csv file that contains `yyyy-mm-ddThh:mm:ss.sssZ` data.

When I set `DATETIME` type in MySQL,

> I got error code 1292.

MySQL How can I upload `yyyy-mm-ddThh:mm:ss.sssZ` type successfully?

[image]

Comment: Could you please share some of your real data? You need to insert the data in a `varchar` type column. Then you need to update the string dates into a valid date format. Only then changing the datatype to `date` would make it a success

Comment: I added picture of my data(csv file). Then, how can I update the string dates into valid date format with uploaded data in DB?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First you need to convert your string dates into a valid date time format (`yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss`).

With the help of `STR_TO_DATE()` and `DATE_FORMAT()` functions you can convert those date strings into the above desired format.

Now you can safely change/modify the datatype to timestamp/datetime.

**Here's a demonstration:**

<kbd>[**SQL FIDDLE DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d1a7c/1/0)</kbd>

---

**Convert string dates into valid date format:**

```
Create table yourtable(
   id INT primary key AUTO_INCREMENT,
   start varchar(50)
);

INSERT INTO yourtable(start) VALUES('1901-02-03T05:30:00.000Z');

UPDATE yourtable
SET start = DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(start,'%Y-%m-%dT%H:%i:%s.000Z'),'%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s');
```

---

**Change the datatype:**

```
ALTER TABLE yourtable MODIFY COLUMN start datetime;
```

Comment: i'm appreciate for your help!!

Comment: You can mark the answer as Accepted so that others find it useful. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work